# javascript setinterval function problem

Tags: javascript

i am using this code

```
 <a onclick="javascript:var t=setInterval("GetUpdates(5,ajaxResult)",300);">GetUpdates</a>
```

but getting the syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var t=setInterval(function(){GetUpdates(5,ajaxResult);},300);
```

You are including a double quote inside the onclick event handler which is causing the problem.

```
<a onclick="javascript:var t=setInterval(function(){GetUpdates(5,ajaxResult);},300);">GetUpdates</a>
```